# Ruby $:unshift '..'

Tags: ruby, file-io

The following is the directory structure of my assignment.
Assign has a symbols.txt, src folder and a test folder in it.

I wrote this at top of my file test file.
$:.unshift '..'

I am passing symbols.txt as a parameter in a test and calling the method in the main class.

```
def test_get_symbols_from_file
    assert(@asset.get_symbols_from_file('symbols.txt'))
end
```

Though I am asking to move to one directory up and look for symbols.txt from this test class, it says

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - symbols.txt

Am I including the wrong path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about that `$:` means. [`$:` is also known as `$LOAD_PATH`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables) and that is the:

> Load path for scripts and binary modules by `load` or `require`.

You'll also find `$:` mentioned in the [`require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require) docs:

> If the `filename` does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be searched for in the directories listed in `$LOAD_PATH` (`$:`).

So `$:` is a search path for `require`, it doesn't have anything to do with normal file operations. You'll have to say:

```
@asset.get_symbols_from_file('../symbols.txt')
```

or

```
@asset.get_symbols_from_file('/some/absolute/path/to/symbols.txt')
```

or build search path support into `get_symbols_from_file`.

Comment: But without ../ the test is passing when I run rake through cmd but it is failing in the editor "SubLime2" and when I put '../' the test is passing in sublime and failing when i run rake. What is the problem? please help

Comment: The problem is that you're assuming things about the current directory that aren't always true, using an absolute path rather than relative paths would solve that problem.